# If A blocks B on Twitter (preventing B from seeing A's tweets), can B block A so that A can't see B's tweets?

Tags: twitter

If A blocks B on Twitter (preventing B from seeing A's tweets), can B block A so that A can't see B's tweets?

Where is the option to block somebody after they have blocked you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**, B can block A, even A already has blocked B.

Go to that person's profile who has blocked you. There you see a message showing that *you are blocked from following that person and viewing that person's tweets*.

There on the right top you will see three vertical dots, click on that, there will be three options: Mute, Block, Report.

So, you can block, mute or report a person who already has blocked you. See the below screenshot for better understanding:[image]

Answer (score -3):

Only the first person to block can do so on Twitter.

As person B has been blocked by person A, there is no ability for person B to even see the existence of person A which to block them bilaterally.

Comment: This answer is straight wrong. See my [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/123820/87130).